# How will more stimulus checks in California affect inflation?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, political-economy

So we're getting more money here in [California](https://www.sfchronicle.com/california/article/California-2022-stimulus-17280588.php). I thought the consensus at this point was that we probably overstimulated the economy. What gives? What was the reasoning economic advisors had for greenlighting this? Am I just massively missing something?

Comment: The link is broken, also what do you mean by what was the reasoning of economic advisors? We can’t see into their heads, for all an outsider can know they could have done it just for “fun”, can you please clarify the question

Comment: @1muflon1 The link is fine as far as I can tell. Obviously we can't know what's going on inside their heads but I seem to remember humans having some capacity to communicate what is going on inside their heads.

Comment: previously there was something wrong with the link maybe it was on Twitter end, on this site we expect users to do some basic background research before asking question. I assumed you look at their statements and didn’t found anything there. If you didn’t have a look at what they say then you should first do that and then edit question to ask about the parts that were confusing you

Comment: They are paying for it from money the Californian government actually has, right? Everyone I talk to insists very strongly that inflation is caused by printing money, and since the Californian government isn't printing money, logically it can't cause inflation /s